# Favourite VS Like The Most

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-meaning

What is the difference between "favourite" and "like the most"?
My mom understands that you can sometimes have more than one favourite, is that correct?

> What is your favourite food?
> Pizza and burgers.
> OR
> Pizza.
>
> What food do you like the most?
> Pizza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can have more than one favorite food, but singular/plural has to be written accordingly.

> What **is** your favorite **food**? Pizza.
>   What **are** your favorite **foods**? Pizza and burgers.

and

> What **food** do you like the most? Pizza.
>   What **foods** do you like the most? Pizza and burgers.

Favorites often follow more specific categories, like favorite chocolate bar or favorite fruit. So even if you want to say you can only have one favorite food, in fact you can have several.

At least for foods, *favorite* and *like the most* mean roughly the same thing. Other contexts may be different.

In case it is not obvious, it is *favorite* in AmE.

Comment: . . .and to clarify, 'favourite' in BrE